# Why python math.factorial(x) is very fast?

Tags: python

I have a question, why python numeric calculation is very fast? 
for example the below code runs shorter than one second

```
import  math
print math.factorial(10000)
```

why???

Comment: The speed of this function heavily depends on the Python version.  It's much faster in Python 3, while you seem to be using Python 2.x.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be fast?

Comment: See [Why is math.factorial much slower in Python 2.x than 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815252/why-is-math-factorial-much-slower-in-python-2-x-than-3-x) for a discussion of the different factorial algorithms in Python 2.x and 3.x.  Closing as duplicate.

Comment: In c code of math_factorial I find that it uses a function that called PyNumber_Multiply, but I did not find it's implementation

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`math` module's functions](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html) are implemented in C:

> It provides access to the mathematical functions defined by the C standard.

By using an efficient algorithm in C, you get fast results.

If you are asking why this particular operation is so fast, then see [Why is math.factorial much slower in Python 2.x than 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815252/why-is-math-factorial-much-slower-in-python-2-x-than-3-x) and the [C code itself](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7937aa6b7e92/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1218).

Comment: The speed of the factorial depends on the complexity of the algorithm.  A straight-forward implementation in C will be much slower than the algorithm used in Python 3.x

Comment: @SvenMarnach: How was I supposed to guess that the OP was comparing python 2 and 3 speeds? :-P

Comment: The result of the algorithm is a number with more that 30000 digits, for this huge numbers calculation you should use array or string, but I'm confused, why it returns result shorter than one second

Comment: Well, I know this is not really a duplicate, but I think everything you could reasonably say as an answer to this question is covered in the other thread.

Comment: "It simply reuses the standard C functions under the hood." – Certainly not for the factorial, which returns an arbitrary-precision integer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yeah, was busy updating the post already but with hg.python.org gone it took me a second to translate the source URL to bitbucket. I've corrected the broken links in the other answer as well.

Comment: Closed? why?? I can edit my question

Comment: @Pooya: Your question was rather vague and we had to guess as to what you were really asking. There is also a case to be made that your question is a duplicate of another. Editing your question could help, but is not a guarantee it'll be reopened.

Comment: Inform the time complexity of math.factorial would be very informative I think.