# How to reduce time complexity of a program for finding length of a factorial in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got stuck with a question in which I have first to find the factorial of a number and then return the number of digits obtained in the factorial.
I wrote the program and it's working fine. But the time is 5.0015 sec and I have to do in 1 sec. How to reduce this?

Below is my program:

```
def factorial(n):
    fact = 1
    for y in xrange(1,n+1):
        fact = fact * y
    return fact

t = int(raw_input())
raw_input()
for x in xrange(t):
    n = int(raw_input())
    print len(str(factorial(n)))
```

Comment: It won't change the time complexity, but it be a lot simpler and probably faster by using built-in functions: `len(str(math.factorial(n)))`.

Comment: I already tried this. But I have to reduce the time complexity

Comment: First of all your code is not very clear. Why are you defining `length` if you are not using it? Why are you looping instead of doing just `print  len(str(factorial(n)))`?

Comment: @HerrActress, this is more than likely an online code problem where you have to use raw_input to take in the arguments

Comment: Even memozation won't get you to a better complexity (but it could improve speed). For an interesting take at the problem, you can review this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815252/why-is-math-factorial-much-slower-in-python-2-x-than-3-x

Comment: Hey Herr Actress, I have used length function to got the length manually but also tried with len (in built function) and just thought to show all the code, what i have tried to implement. that's why i didn't remove the length function.

Answer (score 4):

Use the power of mathematics and avoid calculating the factorial entirely.

The base 10 logarithm of a number is the power to which 10 needs to be raised to be equal to that number. For example, `math.log10(10) == 1`, `math.log10(11) == 1.0413926851582251`, `math.log10(100) == 2`, etc.

This means that the smallest integer *stictly greater* than the log10 of a number, (that is, `ceil(log10(n)) + (1 if log10(n).is_integer() else 0)` ) is the number of digits in that number.

In addition, `log10(a * b) = log10(a) + log10(b)`.

Which means that `log10(factorial(n)) == sum(log10(a) for a in range(1, n+1))`

Finally, the length of that factorial is:

```
math.ceil(sum(math.log10(a) for a in xrange(1, n+1)))
```

(more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)

Comment: Should be added that the final formula fails calculating the length of `1!`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Stirling's approximation for log(n!)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html):

```
from math import ceil, log, pi

def log_fact(n):
    # using Stirling's approximation to calculate log10(n!)
    n = float(n)
    return (
        n * log(n)
        - n
        + log(2 * pi * n) / 2.
        + 1/(  12 * n   )
        - 1/( 360 * n**3)
        + 1/(1260 * n**5)
    ) / log(10)
```

At a guess your value for `n` is around 60000; testing I get

```
import math
n = 60000

%%timeit
# @SheeshMosin
len(str(factorial(n)))                                 # 3.93 s

%%timeit
# @MaxNoel
math.ceil(sum(math.log10(a) for a in range(1, n+1)))   # 16.1 ms
                                                       # (250 times faster)

%%timeit
# @HughBothwell
math.ceil(log_fact(n))                                 # 3.62 µs
                                                       # (1.08 million times faster)
```

Answer (score -4):

You could try making the function recursive.

Comment: And how would that reduce time complexity?

Comment: Recursion won't reduced the complexity, and will start to fail with large numbers, as it would hit the maximum recursion depth